# Error message while plotting density functions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I had a data frame with 750 observations and 250 columns, and I would like to plot two density plots on top of each other. In one case, a particular factor is present, in the other it isn't (commercial activities against non-commercial activities).

I created a subset of the data

```
CommercialActivityData <- subset(MbadSurvey, Q2== 1)
NonCommercialActivityData <- subset(MbadSurvey, Q2== 2)
```

I then tried to plot this as follows

```
p1 <- ggplot(CommercialActivityData, aes(x = water_use_PP)) + geom_density()
p1
```

However, when I do, I get the following error message

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (51): x
```

I have 51 data values where there is commercial, and 699 where there isn't.

Comment: please share your sample data

Comment: How does one share data? Sorry, I'm new to StackExchange

Comment: just paste your sample data in text box just like when you ask a query in stackExchange

Comment: 187.50000
2
2
40.00000
3
2
100.00000
4
2
78.12500
5
2
150.00000
6
2
125.00000
7
2
4.25000
8
2
125.00000
9
2
333.33333
10
2
125.00000
11
2
125.00000
12
2
62.50000
13
2
40.00000
14
2
70.83333
15
2
150.00000
16
2
67.85714
17
2
89.28571
18
2
125.00000
19
2
250.00000

Comment: I don't think I know how to do that - sorry

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: new code!!

I don't have access to your data set so I have simulated your data:

```
# Creating the data frame
MbadSurvey <- data.frame("water_use_PP"=runif(1000,1,100),
                 "Q2"=as.factor(round(runif(1000,1,2),0)))

# Requiring the package
require(ggplot2)

# Creating 3 different density plots based on the Species
p1 <- ggplot(MbadSurvey, aes(x = water_use_PP,colour = Q2)) + geom_density()
p1
```

[image]

NOTE: The variable `Q2` must be a factor!

Comment: That is what I want. However, when i the same code, I only get one line, not the three. I assume iris is the dataframe, sepal.length is the parameter value, and it groups it by the different values in Species

Comment: hum... that's strange. Can you try cleaning the objects in your workspace and make sure you run exactly the code I've posted here (I've edited to include the require(ggplot2))?
Also, can you run packageVersion("ggplot2") please and tell me the version of your ggplot2.

Comment: I'm running 2.1.0. What I mean to say is that I did get the same results as you did with the iris data. However, when i use may data (which I think is the same - I have one variable that can be either 1 or 2 (in the same way your data has 3 values for species. And I have another parameter that has values all the way between 0 and 1000 and that's what I want to plot

Comment: Ok, so instead of `Species` you should put `Q2`, instead of `Sepal.Length` you should write `water_use_PP` and instead of `iris` you should use `MbadSurvey`.

Comment: Of course - but when I do that, I only get one line, not the two I am expecting!

Comment: I've got what your problem is. I've edited my solution to solve your problem. Take a look.

Comment: That's perfect - is the problem that I wasn't using categorical data for Q2? That's a really big help

Comment: Yeah, probably using factor is probably even better than categorical. Can you accept my answer as the right one please?